# call const member function from the c'tor

Tags: c++, constructor, constants

why can't I call const member function from the c'tor?
I have tried this code:
How the compiler know *a is now member variable?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class A {
  public:
    A():abc(NULL)
   {
     cout<<"c'tor"<<endl;
     f(abc);
   }
   ~A(){}
    void f(float* a) const
    {
        *a=4; //crashed here
    }
    float* getAbc()
    {
        return abc;
    }
     private:
       float* abc;
};

int main()
{
   A a;
   cout<<a.getAbc()<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why on the earth do you want to dereference `NULL` in this test?

Comment: You can, and your code does that, with the consequence of crashing the program, as programmed by you.

Answer (score 3):

`const` has nothing to do with the problem here.

The problem is due to your dereferencing the member `abc` (albeit through the copy to the parameter `a` in the function `f`) without it pointing to anything. Your constructor sets `abc` to `NULL`.

The behaviour on doing that is undefined. Also, consider using `nullptr` in newer C++ standards.

Comment: So if I would change that, it would change a as if it was abc?  although its const?

Comment: Yes, that would be fine. All `const` essentially does in a function is change the type of `this` to a `const`, and that function doesn't reference any member data. I think you should contrive a better example and ask another question.

Answer (score 2):

When your code reaches

```
*a=4;
```

`a` is `NULL`.  Trying to dereference and use a null pointer is undefined behavior.  You need to create a `new` float in the constructor to make `a` valid.  To do that just change

```
A():abc(NULL)
```

To

```
A():abc(new float)
```

If you do that then you need to implement a destructor to delete the pointer an a copy constructor to properly copy it.  Instead of doing all that you could just not use a pointer and have just a `float`.